How do I resolved process error in docusaurus project
I'm using Firebase to integrate with Docusaurus project for storage and retrieval. I have a .env file containing the firebase keys. I also have firebase config file.
I have been having process is not defined error
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./firebaseConfig.js:16:30)
    at ./firebaseConfig.js (http://localhost:3000/content---feedback-9-e-5-de5.js:22:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.js:34:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.js:334:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/Feedback.js:8:73)
    at ./src/pages/Feedback.js (http://localhost:3000/content---feedback-9-e-5-de5.js:29:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.js:34:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.js:334:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/feedback.md:12:82)
    at ./src/pages/feedback.md (http://localhost:3000/content---feedback-9-e-5-de5.js:15:1)

I Exposed Environment Variables in Docusaurus by updating docusaurus.config.js to use the environment variables correctly.
but still getting the process error.
customFields: {
        firebaseConfig: {
          apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
          projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
          storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
          messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
          measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
        },
      },

